# check if javascript var is equal to string

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page the verifies the username users type in, and echo's back "available!" if its available into a div called "feedback". now I have this JavaScript that I want to check to see if the "feedback" div says "available! and echo "username good" into the "check" div if it is. but it doesn't work and i don't know why.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>

  
 function check_info(){
 var username_good = document.getElementById('feedback').value;
 
 
 if(username_good == "available!"){
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "username good";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "bad"; 

 }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing one of those echoes server-side and one client-side? Why not just echo "username good" in the same place that you're echoing "available"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div doesn't have a `value` property, you need to use `innerHTML`:

```
var username_good = document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/yvys27hs/) for the same added.

```
<div id="feedback">test</div>
<div id="check"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="javascript:check_info()" value="Validate">

function check_info(){
    var username_good = document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML;
    if(username_good !== ""){
       document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "username good";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "bad"; 

    }
}
```